# How to Fix popup buttons logic

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have the following popup where a user is able to enter three fields and when they click 'ok'. The popup should simply disappear. As of now, when I click on the ok button, nothing happens, the popup just stays there, the same goes for when I click the 'Cancel' button, nothing happens either. What am I missing that when I press the 'OK' button, it does not disappear? Why are the buttons not doing anything when I click on them?

**EDIT:**
After placing a breakpoint on my ok button logic, I get a hit on that, however, I think my main question here is if there is a way for the popup to close after clicking on ok, hence, the user is done entering data.

As for the cancel button, it does not trigger when the breakpoint when clicking on the button.

[image]

**XAML CODE**

```
 <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"
                        Grid.Row="2">
                    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">

                        <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
                                     Content="_Cancel" Margin="4,2"  MinWidth="60"/>

                        <Button x:Name="btnOk" Command="{Binding Path=OKCommand}"
                                     Content="_OK" Margin="4,2"  MinWidth="60"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Border>
```

**ViewModel Code**

```
public event CancelHandler OnCancel;
public delegate void CancelHandler();

public ICommand CancelCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(c => OnCancelLock()); }
}

public ICommand OKCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(c => OnOKLock()); }
}


    protected void OnOKLock()
{

    var currentSetting = AppSession.Repository.Settings.Find(SettingQuery.ID == new ID("LockedOutDate"));
    currentSetting[0].Value = LockedOutDate;
    AppSession.Repository.Settings.Save(currentSetting[0]);

    currentSetting = AppSession.Repository.Settings.Find(SettingQuery.ID == new ID("LockedOutBy"));
    currentSetting[0].Value = LockedOutBy;
    AppSession.Repository.Settings.Save(currentSetting[0]);

    currentSetting = AppSession.Repository.Settings.Find(SettingQuery.ID == new ID("LockedOutFor"));
    currentSetting[0].Value = LockedOutFor;
    AppSession.Repository.Settings.Save(currentSetting[0]);

    currentSetting = AppSession.Repository.Settings.Find(SettingQuery.ID == new ID("IsUsersLockedOut"));
    currentSetting[0].Value = "1"; 
    AppSession.Repository.Settings.Save(currentSetting[0]);

}

protected void OnCancelLock()
{
   OnCancel();
}
```

Comment: When debugging this, did you see that the relevant code for each button gets triggered?

Comment: also, there is no code that can close a window

Comment: @tomerpacific the ok button gets triggered, but not the cancel button.

Comment: @vasily.sib So when I hit the ok button, there is no way for the popup to close after?

Comment: @JohnVasquez - Pleaae edit your question, because that is not clear. You state that both buttons don't work...

Comment: @JohnVasquez sure there is a way. There is dozens of ways. I mean that your code isn't even trying to close the window, why do you expect that window will close?

Comment: @vasily.sib what would you recommend? I have tried using this.closeview() and going into the xaml.cs to play around with the btn.ispressed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is right here:

```
 <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
                                 Content="_Cancel" Margin="4,2"  MinWidth="60"/>
```

You defined your binding to be CloseCommand, but in your ViewModel code you wrote:

```
public ICommand CancelCommand
{
  get { return new RelayCommand(c => OnCancelLock()); } 
}
```

So either change it to CloseCommand in your ViewModel or CancelCommand in your XAML file.

Comment: Thank you for catching that, however, I now get an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error

Comment: @JohnVasquez - where are you getting it from? Please update your question with ALL the relevant information.